# Eloquent Javascript Chapter 7 - gamblerPath function

Tags: javascript, function

Inside the gamblerPath function in  [Chapter 7](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter7.html#p1e5bca09b5aefa17) the function randomInteger is doing what the name says, choosing a random integer.

```
function gamblerPath(from, to) {
  function randomInteger(below) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * below);
  }
  function randomDirection(from) {
    var options = roadsFrom(from);
    return options[randomInteger(options.length)].to;
  }

  var path = [];
  while (true) {
    path.push(from);
    if (from == to)
      break;
    from = randomDirection(from);
  }
  return path;
}

show(gamblerPath("Hanaiapa", "Mt Feani"));
```

My doubt is related to *randomInteger*'s argument of **below**, where does it come from ? It's not being passed when the function is called. Anyone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `randomInteger(options.length)`, the parameter `options.length` is the value for `below`.

In other words, you want a random number that's less than the size of the array, so you can pick a random value from the array.

Comment: As a beginner I find it hard to follow this kind of abstract path that a function can have. Therefore thanks for the explanation.